# Testing changes in static library?

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

We have some static libraries and a main app. We do this so we can ship each bit separately if we need to.

I'm coming across a frustrating problem however. Everytime I make a change to the library and I want to test it/run it I have to compile it (+ lipo etc to make a Fat binary) then copy and paste into my other project (app) and then use the app to test it.

Is this the only way that I can test what I want to test? I know about unit tests, but we're using those for build server tests. All I want to do is test some new functionality I'm building in my static library.

How do you guys do it? Is it even possible or is the way I've described the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a "test" app that uses the library, and include the library(s) project(s) in that. You will be able to change your library code, and then run the test app immediately.

I'm doing this exact thing now, as I'm developing a static library for my companies customers.

Or, even easier, just include the library projects in the apps. The only downside to this is that you won't have the EXACT same process as others you distribute to.

Comment: Yeah we used to do it that second way (including the library in the apps) but it just made it difficult for us when trying to document and support clients. :) The first thing is perhaps a good idea. Make a "test" app. Thanks

Comment: Sure - I understand as I just had so bundle a library for a client, and had to develop a second app where I could include the .a and the headers - just to make sure it really did work! You could just duplicate one of your current apps, delete the library, and add in the library projects. Hmmm - maybe you can have two targets in the apps - one that uses the included library, the other that uses the .a files etc? If the Project settings make no reference to either, and the targets do, perhaps it will work (I should try this myself too! :-)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately for our situation that's probably not possible. We will be delivering the source code for the app, but not the libraries to our clients, so it could get a bit unmanageable making sure we don't accidentally deliver the source code! Your answer has given me food for thought, so thank you very much. I'll see if we can go with some sort of test app, possibly on a separate git branch. :)